# SSIS Conditional split expression gives unexpected result

Tags: ssis, guid, logical-operators

In SSIS I have the following expressions in a Conditional Split Transformation Editor :

**Output name  :      Condition**

```
Case 1 :            (ISNULL(ContactId) && ISNULL(AccountId))

Case 2 :           !(ISNULL(ContactId) && ISNULL(AccountId))

else default
```

Both `ContactId` and `AccountId` are of the type `DT_GUID`
I expect to go to `"Case 1" when both ContactId and AccountId are null.`
In reality I see that the flow is routed to `"Case 1" only when ContactId is null **or** [AccountId] is null.`

*Am I not seeing something obvious?*

Comment: There does not seem to be anything obvious your missing.. Can you attach some screenshots of your conditional split editor?

Comment: I worked around it by adding a column with a case statement to the base query.

But tx anyway @TMNT2014